# Event - How to know if invited user has permission to invite friends to the event

Tags: rest, facebook-graph-api

So using the object located at "Core Concepts › Graph API › Event" I can get users that have been invited to the event with different filters, attending, unsure... etc.

How can I know from these lists I can GET if they are allowed to invite friends? In other words, how can I know their permission in regards to the event using the Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

`fql?q=SELECT can_invite_friends FROM event WHERE eid=EVENT_ID`

Comment: is there any way to set this parameter to false for an event you create programtically ?